# Google Earth Pro not working after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: applications, catalina, crash, google-maps, 64-bit

After I upgraded my macOS to Catalina on my MacBook Pro 2018 (13.3", i5, 16GB RAM, TouchBar), Google Earth Pro will not open anymore.

When I launch the app, it opens the window but it will freeze and there's this annoying spinning beach ball. I have to force quit to quit the application.

What I've tried:

- I installed an older version of Google Earth Pro, but that did not solve the issue.
- I also cleared out the cache, turned off atmosphere, and my places in the repair window.

Does anyone have the same issue, is there anyway to fix this?

I can use the online (browser) version, but I'd like to use the application because it has more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  Google's help wasn't very helpful.  I reset my MacBook's SMC and it works fine.  Link to steps for any Mac: https://www.macworld.com/article/224955/how-to-reset-a-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html

Hope this might help, although a year later.